# Trying to open up a socket connection to USB device in linux using fsockopen()

Tags: php, linux, port, fsockopen

I am experimenting with PHP `fsocket` open to open up a socket port. I would like to try to open a socket connection to my `/dev/ttyUSB0` (USB) in Linux. I believe `fsocket` likes the par maters `fsockopen(hostname, port)`. The port parameter requires an integer. I would like to know if I can find the physical port address number linked to my `/dev/ttyUSB0` device

Comment: fsocket can talk to a program on the same machine over a UNIX domain socket, or a program on a remote machine over an internet socket. In either case the program must have a corresponding socket. What program are you trying to talk to?

Comment: @Monfonya - Maybe you confuse an USB socket with a TCP or a UNIX domain socket?

Comment: I believe  Armali is  right  I did get confused between USB and TCP/UNIX domain socket. Sorry for the error. Thanks helping me get that straightened out. I did find a php class that will work with /dev/tty devices. Thank you again for straightening my error.